# How i create an android widget size like the app icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-widget, android-appwidget

I've created a 1x1 Widget with an ImageView and a TextView. When placing the  widget onto the Home screen, the widget should look like the launcher icon of this app. However, it is not similar. I have try to resizing the Image but no success.

**Update**

Problem is solved, I've changed the layout gravity from center to top!
Thx for help!

Comment: "If I drag the widget to the Home screen, the widget should look like the app icon of this app" -- home screens can implement "the app icon of this app" however they want. There is no requirement for a particular size, font, etc.

Comment: Have you tired a 9-patch image file?  that will allow the image to stretch and compress where you want, to allow for different size screens.

Comment: Can you show the code with the solution?

Comment: The problem was the gravity of the content layout , after I change it from center to left,  it works

Comment: @eddykordo Do you mind sharing the code with us?

Comment: @Skyyy looking for the same!